# Windows Activation "Forgets" It's Been Activated

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-activation

Last week, I installed Windows 7 Ultimate x64, activated online, and everything went smoothly. However, every day after midnight, Windows informs me that it hasn't been activated (via the version number and text on the desktop). If I go to "My Computer | Properties", however, the windows "genuine" seal appears and the desktop text disappears. Does anyone know why this is happening? And is there a way to stop it? I have a genuine copy of the OS.

Thank you.

Comment: A number of questions that might help figure out what's going on if Microsoft is not being helpful.

Is it a retail, OEM, promotional, or upgrade version? Also, do you leave the system on all the time or shut it down regularly? Does the system time change at all? How old is this hardware?

"Desktop Text disappears" is a rather odd thing to have happen, is there anything else "strange" that happens?

Comment: It's a copy from MSDN. I do leave the system on all the time. The system time does not change and the hardware is about 3-yo. What I meant by "desktop text disappears" is that the Activation reminder text on the desktop disappears. 

I might have found an answer here: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7install/thread/1af25807-dbba-4f2b-8f51-76da6fc12f70, but I don't know if it's a permanent solution. I'm afraid it's just delaying the text from appearing for a few days/months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured this out. I had set the "Software Protection" service to manual.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic job for [Microsoft Support](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/activation-centers.aspx).  If you phone them eventually you can even get through to a human.